# Experimental Long Polling in Firebase Web v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cypress

I am attempting to set `experimentalForceLongPolling = true` for Firestore settings.

The reason for this is because without this, Firestore does not work with emulators in Cypress testing.

How does one set the settings, specifically this `experimentalForceLongPolling` setting, in the Firebase Web v9 SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `initializeFirestore` instead of `getFirestore` to update any settings as shown below:

```
import { initializeFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

const db = initializeFirestore(app, { experimentalForceLongPolling: true })
```